# Web/Firebase - I cannot access the realtime database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, create-react-app

I cannot read or write to the firebase real-time database... please help.

I have set my rules to both read and write 'true', and I've tested it in the playground.
I'm using the create-react-app boilerplate setup.
My version of the firebase is 9.6.4

Here's my firebase file

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase, set, ref } from 'firebase/database';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'AIzamGZ1LBAAtb',
    authDomain: 'helpme.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://helpme.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'helpme',
    storageBucket: 'helpme.appt.com',
    messagingSenderId: '93help1',
    appId: '1:293268271119:web:d4e9e73help',
    measurementId: 'helpKQLWS',
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(app);

set(ref(db, 'chatroom'), {
    name: '',
    createdAt: '',
    photo: '',
});
```

Comment: I hope these aren’t your real credentials… Please change your firebase credentials for security’s sake and don’t EVER post your credentials on the internet. Otherwise any fool could acces your database

Comment: They're not any real data.

Comment: @CasperKuethe While I agree that it's not necessary to post the app configuration on Stack Overflow, please note that the information in `firebaseConfig` are configuration data and **not** credentials. See my answer here for a longer explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public/37484053#37484053

Comment: Better safe than sorry ‍♂️